# Powershell grabbing extra files

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have this Powershell code:

```
Function CheckFileList()
{
    $limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-270)
    $input_path = gci '//blah/folder/' | sort -property LastWriteTime
    $output_file = 'c:\PowershellScripts\prune_results.txt'
    #Clear-Content $output_file
    $countf = 0
    $outputstr = ""

    $outputstr = $(Get-Date -format 'F') + " - Folders to be purged:`r`n"

    $input_path | Foreach-Object{
        if ( (Get-Item $_.FullName) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] ) {
            if ( $_.LastWriteTime -le $limit ) {
                $source=$input_path + $_.Name
                $dest="\\server\otherfolder" + $_.Name
                $what=@("/MOVE")
                $options=@("/COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T")
                $cmdArgs = @("$source","$dest",$what,$options)
                "robocopy " + $cmdArgs >> $output_file
                #robocopy @cmdArgs
                #Move-Item $_.FullName \\server\otherfolder
                $outputstr = $outputstr + " (" + $_.LastWriteTime + ") `t" + $_.Name + "`r`n"
                $countf++
                $outputstr = $outputstr + "Folders [to be] purged: " + $countf + "`r`n`r`n"
                $outputstr >> $output_file
                Exit
            }
        }
    }

    #$outputstr = $outputstr + "Folders [to be] purged: " + $countf + "`r`n`r`n"
    #$outputstr >> $output_file

}

CheckFilelist
```

This code is just for displaying how the command will run. It's only 1 loop (exits after first loop), so it should have grabbed 1 folder.

But the output was giant, and seemed to included all the folders (1000+) instead of just one. It was something like:

```
robocopy file1.txt FOLDER1 FOLDER2 FOLDER3 FOLDER4 ........ \\server\otherfolder\FOLDER5
```

Am I missing something here? It should be moving folders on `//blah/folder/` to a different network folder (`\\server\otherfolder`)

Comment: This line `$source=$input_path + $_.Name` your `$source` would contain multiple files i think since input path comes from `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: Which folder is it supposed to grab? The one written to last? There are several issues here I see that I am not sure what the intention is

Comment: @Matt Updated my question with from-to on which folders

Comment: So you are making multiple individual calls for robocopy then? One call for each folder that matches the criteria? Robocopy will natively copy data based on date without the need to have individual calls.

Comment: @Matt The individual calls are for making sure the folder is older than 270 days (Powershell checking that), and it makes the log file look clean. Unless you mean there's still a better way to accomplish this in 1 cmd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of your issue is coming from how you are populating `$source`

```
$source=$input_path + $_.Name
```

Which is because of how you define `$input_path`

```
$input_path = gci '//blah/folder/' | sort -property LastWriteTime
```

You go on loop through all the item while only looking for one really. There are also other ways to reach the same conclusion. `$input_path` is not a path but a collection of folders and files in "//blah/folder"

```
$input_path = gci 'c:\temp' | Where-Object{($_.LastWriteTime -le $limit) -and ($_.PSIsContainer)}
$input_path | ForEach-Object{
    #... do things
    $_.FullName
    # Fullname is the complete path. 
}
```

**About Robocopy**

I think much of this logic could be made redundant if you look at `/MINAGE` in the robocopy documentation

> **/MINAGE:n** Excludes files with a Last Modified Date newer than n days or specified date. If n is less than 1900, then n is expressed in days. Otherwise, n is a date expressed as YYYYMMDD.

Although after reading you comments and question again this is most likely not what you are looking for.

**About `Move-Item`**

I see you were trying that as well. That should work just fine with using our new `$input_path` piped into `Move-Item`. If you need logging you could use a `ForEach-Object` to allow extra information to be logged elsewhere.

```
$input_path | Move-Item -Destination "\\server\otherfolder"
```

Comment: Right I see it now, so source should really just be `//blah/folder/ + $_.Name` or the sort

Comment: Better yet use the `$_.FullName` which contains the full path.

Comment: Alternately, to test for a folder, you can also use ```Test-Path $_.FullName -PathType Container``` to see if it's a folder, or use ```Leaf``` instead of container to check for a file.

Comment: `MINAGE` applies to folders? It should only be looking at folders and not files.

Comment: @zeno maybe im wrong about minage...... havent used robocopy in a while. Tacking on a disclaimer until im sure. You want to copy folder and files yes?

Comment: Right, moving the folder and all files within it (but only checking the folder modified date and not any file dates)